# Dynamic checkboxes adding/deleting to the LinearLayout VS ListView

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, adapter

I have a array which I get from another Activity. I want to display it in the current Activity as CheckBox items and then have ability to check  some of them and delete by button clicking. I implement it next way:

```
  public void addFiles()
        {

             LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.filesList);

            if(!FileManagerActivity.finalAttachFiles.isEmpty())
            {   

                for (int i=0; i<FileManagerActivity.finalAttachFiles.size();i++)
                {   


                    View line = new View(this);
                    line.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(1, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    line.setBackgroundColor(0xAA345556);
                    informationView= new CheckBox(this);
                    informationView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                    informationView.setTextSize(16);
                    informationView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                    informationView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.file_icon, 0, 0, 0);
                    informationView.setText(FileManagerActivity.finalAttachFiles.get(i).getName().toString());
                    informationView.setId(i);
                    layout.addView(informationView, 0);
                    layout.addView(line, 1);
                    layout.postInvalidate();


                }
            }

        }
```

, and call it in the onCreate() method. it can be added successfully. Then I get items which were checked like this:

```
  btnFilesRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.filesList);
            View v = null;
            for(int i=0; i<FileManagerActivity.finalAttachFiles.size(); i++) {
                v = layout.getChildAt(i);

                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(i);
                boolean checked=checkBox.isChecked();
                if (checked)
                {  
                    Log.i("was checked",checkBox.getText().toString());
                    ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
                    parent.removeView(v);
                    FileManagerActivity.finalAttachFiles.remove(i);
                    Log.i("this is view,baby",v.toString());

                }

            }


        }
    });
```

But items can't be deleted. And I'm thinking - what is better - to implement it in this way or maybe it will be more efficient with ListView using. I mean to create ArrayAdapter e.t.c..

Comment: Refer to this tutorial http://kalandarandroid.blogspot.in/2012/03/creating-multiselect-listview-in.html

Comment: Thank you...Can it be some prolblems, if I use ListView in ScrollView?

Comment: No need to use scrollview. listview will automatically scroll if no of items are more

Comment: But I already use the ScrollView in my app..

Comment: If you have to display other views along with listview u need scroll view otherwise no need to use

Comment: I have a lot of items at the screen which should be scrollable...So I need to use ScrollView...or I can do it in some different way?